# Excel: Need to sum the lowest 5 values from a column of 10

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to build an Excel formula that will sum the 5 lowest golf scores out of 10. Currently using a table setup, provided by another forum, but it's not quite getting me there, as I think it's ignoring duplicates. The letter 'E' should also be equal to the value of zero.

Screen shot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2Cka.jpg

Here are the formulae in use, identified by cell:

```
G17: =SUM(IF(G5:G14<=G25,G5:G14)/COUNTIF(G5:G14,G5:G14))

G21: =MIN(G5:G14)

G22: =SMALL($G$5:$G$14,COUNTIF($G5:$G14,"<="&G21)+1)

G23: =SMALL($G$5:$G$14,COUNTIF($G5:$G14,"<="&G22)+1)

G24: =SMALL($G$5:$G$14,COUNTIF($G5:$G14,"<="&G23)+1)

G25: =SMALL($G$5:$G$14,COUNTIF($G5:$G14,"<="&G24)+1)
```

The result in G17 should be -7, but I'm not getting there just yet. Your generous help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, entered as an array formula (CTRL-ENTER):

```
=SUM(SMALL(scores,{1,2,3,4,5}))
```

where scores is the range of cells with your scores

**Update for Google Sheets**

This can also work in Google Sheets, but it seems like it requires an `ArrayFormula`. You enter the above with CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER or manually type the array formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(SMALL(scores,{1,2,3,4,5})))
```

Comment: Actually, with this method of an Array formula [using constants specifically identified within {}'s], you don't need to use CTRL Enter or CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER to resolve. You can just use Enter like any other function.

Comment: Thank you, this is such an elegant solution!

Comment: @Grade 'Eh' Bacon --- thanks, I did not know that it would work w/o an array formula

Comment: Yes it's a useful feature as I tend to avoid Array Formulas in anything which will be opened by someone else to prevent breakage; I would vote your answer up if my voting feature was not broken somehow; it is quite elegant.

Comment: Does this function not work in Google Sheets? I am using it for the exact same reason(golf scores), but its giving me this error SMALL has no valid input data.

Comment: @UtdMan I updated the answer so that it works for Google Sheets

Answer (score 0):

You have made this more confusing than it needs to be.

Assume your golf scores are in any number of rows in column A. In column B, we want to pick up the 5 lowest scores. This can be written as follows, starting with B1 and copied down for as many low places you want to check:

```
=Small(A:A,row())
```

row() returns the current row that the formula is on (to start with, row 1, with B1).

Then on cell C1, simply sum these results, and that's all you need:

```
=SUM(B:B)
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! Also see below for xidgel's solution, it works perfectly.